# Sorting a through a list of words in python

Tags: python

i'm writing a program where the user guesses letters in a secret word (The game hangman)
After the user has guessed a correct letter, it generates a string in the format "t _ _ t".
i'm trying to write a program that compares this guess with a word kist and prints the words 
that are the possible answers (similiar length and contains the guessed letters in the same Index)

here is my code thus far

...

```
def match_with_gaps(my_word, other_word):
    my_word_edited = my_word.split()
    the_len_my_word = len(my_word_edited)
    words_with_same_length = []
    i = " "    
    for word in other_word:
        the_len_other_word = len(word)
        if the_len_other_word == the_len_my_word:
            for i in range(the_len_my_word):
                letter_in_my_word = my_word_edited[i]
                letter_in_other_word = word[i]
                # if letter_in_my_word != "_"
                if letter_in_my_word == letter_in_other_word:
                    words_with_same_length.append(word)  
    print(words_with_same_length)
```

...

Comment: Sounds like a good job for [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).  I'm picturing `re.match(f'^{my_word.replace("_", ".")}$', other_word, re.IGNORECASE)`.

Comment: What is your specific question here? What does not work? Where do you need help?

Comment: With the way I wrote the code if a word was guessed say (w _ _ h)... It outputs all four letter words that starts with 'w' and all four letter words that ends with "h".... But my goal is to output only words that both start with "w" and end with "h"

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient approach would be to use a regular expression on a list of words contained in a single (multiline) strings with one line per word.

```
with open("/usr/share/dict/words","r") as wordList:
    allWords =  wordList.read().lower()

import re
def matchGaps(my_word):
    seenLetters = "".join(set(my_word.lower()))
    pattern     = "^"+my_word.lower().replace("_",f"[^{seenLetters}]")+"$"        
    return re.findall(pattern,allWords,re.MULTILINE)
```

output:

```
print(matchGaps("tre_")) # will not propose "tree"
['tref', 'trek', 'trey']

print(matchGaps("tr__")) # will not propose "trot"
['trag', 'trah', 'tram', 'tran', 'trap', 'tray', 'tree', 'tref', 'trek', 'trey', 'trey', 'trig', 'trim', 'trin', 'trio', 'trio', 'trip', 'trix', 'trod', 'trog', 'tron', 'trow', 'troy', 'troy', 'trub', 'true', 'trug', 'trun', 'tryp']

print(matchGaps("_ree")) 
['bree', 'cree', 'dree', 'free', 'gree', 'tree']
```